# Ajax Div Reload after 5 seconds

Tags: jquery, ajax

i have seen many examples but they all seem to call a ".php" file.

What i would like to do is rather simple in terms of logic.

I need to auto refresh a div that contains PHP that fetches mysql data.

Is there anyway to do this without calling another .php file.

Div name:  #autoload

```
<div id="autoload">phpdata</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this isn't possible, and I wouldn't recommend doing it that way either.

It's best to separate your PHP code into another file, and then request that file with AJAX.

Comment: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20351075/how-to-call-the-ajax-page-in-same-page) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7561569/jquery-ajax-passing-value-on-php-same-page) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060714/ajax-request-to-same-page)

Answer (score 0):

If I'm correct you are trying to refresh a specific `div` with new content every 5 secs. One solution could be to use javascript setInterval like:

**javascript**

```
function refreshContent() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/echo/json/' //here is the php file that returns the new data
    }).done(function () {
        $("#autoload").append("new content")
    });
}

setInterval(refreshContent, 5000);
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vjdLb48k/)